# Finding uitextfields by tag

Tags: uiview, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have multiple textfields on my view, and each time a textfield is taped a picker appears(the picker was made by code). This works fine for the first textfield, I can also select a row and the textfield receives it. But when I tap the second one and the picker appears, the row selected appears on the first textfield. I know I can use "tag" to distinguish them, but then I get stuck...it doesn´t work.

Does anyone have/has this problem? What method do I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try creating one picker for each textfield   pick1,pick2.......then in the

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

method u check

```
if( pickerview==pick1)
{
text1.text=  (pick1 value at row);
}
else if(pickerview==pick2)
{
text2.text= (pick2 value at row);
}
```